# Apache http proxy and reverse proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, httpserver, proxypass

I need to define two virtual host that should forward my requests to different web applications.
IP of PC where appache is installed is: 192.168.100.208.
IP of application server where application are installed is: 192.168.100.50

```
<VirtualHost *:7778>
ServerName 192.168.100.208

ProxyRequests On
ProxyPreserveHost Off
<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyErrorOverride On

ProxyPass / http://192.168.100.50:9081/app1/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.100.50:9081/app1/

 <Location>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
</Location>
```

and I need to have:

```
<VirtualHost *:7777>
ServerName 192.168.100.208

ProxyRequests On
ProxyPreserveHost Off
<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyErrorOverride On

ProxyPass / http://192.168.100.50:9081/app2/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.100.50:9081/app2/

 <Location>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
</Location>
```

So when I type in browser:

```
192.168.100.208:7778 i should get page from 192.168.100.50:9081/app1
```

and

```
192.168.100.208:7777 i should get page from 192.168.100.50:9081/app2
```

But above is not working. Where is mistake?

Comment: anybody? this should not be hard to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to have the following configured also:

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:7778
NameVirtualHost *:7777
```